# Monthly Report in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm developing a project which is a Hotel Reservation System.

My problem is I want to loop every month like 1 is January 2 is February and so on. If its 1 then It will get all the row which the month is 1 or January by Comparing it to the `cout_created` column on the mySQL database table and add all the profits for each record, putting it later inside an array like this:

```
$monthlyreport = [
   1 => 6000,
   2 => 5000,
   3 => 3000,
   4 => 12000,
   5 => 8000,
   6 => 4000,
   7 => 6000,
   8 => 9000,
   9 => 4000,
   10 => 6000,
   11 => 9000,
   12 => 4000,
];
```

This is the mySQL Database table schema for a example row:

```
 Row Name      Row Data

id            9
gst_id        1
cout_tin      2018-07-01
cout_tout     2018-07-02
cout_nodays   1
cout_single   1
cout_double   2
cout_family   1
cout_roombal  13000
cout_billbal  1120
cout_totalbal 14120
cout_downbal  6500
cout_result   7620
cout_created  2018-07-15 09:34:12
```

I'm using PHP with Codeigniter framework.

Comment: It's hard to understand... first what I understand is you are using a Database with the structure you show here on your post... then, what you look for the month? `cout_created`? `cout_tin`? `cout_tout`? Is this MySQL? MongoDB? Give more details on that and I'll try to give you a hand. Is it is as I'm thinking, the solution is pretty easy.

Comment: its in the cout_created sir. its a timestamp and Im using MySQL. I'm sorry Sir.

Comment: Ok, writing the answer for you now :)

Comment: Thank you for the Time Sir.

Comment: give it a try and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Ok. I will sir after my class. It's a minor subject So I can't try it now. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is combining database queries with a simple for loop in PHP.

First, you have to understand how to get all the values inside the month. `cout_created` is a timestamp/datetime field.
In MySQL, you can get the data using a query like this one:

`SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE MONTH(cout_created) = XX`

Using this query, in PHP you will go for this:

```
// Initialize the array
$monthlyreport = array();
// For each month we are gonna do the same
for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    // We get the results with database library, changing the sql according to our needs.
    $sql = "SELECT cout_result FROM yourtable WHERE MONTH(cout_created) = " . $month; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    // The accum variable to sum all the profits.
    $sum = 0;      
    // And foreach record, we sum the value to the actual one.
    foreach($query->result() as $row) {
       $sum = $sum + $row->cout_result;
    }
    // When finish, save the result on the array and start again.
    $montlyreport[$month] = $sum;
}
```

That would be the easiest way to understand how to do it, but we can do it even better. MySQL allow us to do the same by using its built-in [SUM() function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) directly on MySQL, so we don't have to make additional processing on PHP. We can do this:

```
// Initialize the array
$monthlyreport = array();
// For each month we are gonna do the same
for ($month = 1; $month <= 12; $month++) {
    // But now we will get sum of the values instead of each value
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(cout_result) as profit FROM yourtable WHERE MONTH(cout_created) = " . $month; 
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    // And just save the profit
    $montlyreport[$month] = $query->row()->profit;
}
```

I have not tested it as I don't have a PHP environment here for testing, but let me know how it works and I'll update the answer accordingly.

---

EDIT: I have come with another solution that with solve it with only one query to the database, but it will depend of the performance with your database size and number of records:

`SELECT SUM(cout_result) as profit, MONTH(cout_created) as mymonth 
 FROM yourtable 
 GROUP BY MONTH(cout_created)`

With this, you just need to iterate with the `foreach` saving every profit directly by the `mymonth`

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(cout_result) as profit, MONTH(cout_created) as mymonth FROM yourtable GROUP BY MONTH(cout_created)"
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$monthlyreport = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $monthlyreport[$row->mymonth] = $row->profit;
}
```

Comment: @Alpha_Bords You're welcome. Glad to have helped you.

Answer (score -1):

```
$currentyear_result=array();
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $year_record =$this->db->where('YEAR(created_at)', date('Y'))->where('MONTH(created_at)', date($i))->count_all_results('order_details');
        if (!empty($year_record)) {
                $currentyear_result[$i] =$lastyear_record;
            } else {
                $currentyear_result[$i] = 0;
            }
        }

Output: Array (
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0 )
```